# PowerShell - Close running script with another script

Tags: windows-10, command-line, powershell, script, scheduled-tasks

I have 3 PS Scripts, **STOP.ps1**, **FORM.ps1** and **ENABLE.ps1**.

ENABLE.ps1 will create a task in task scheduler that opens the **FORM.ps1** script every hour.

Once the FORM gets opened, there is a button to close the form once all textboxes are filled out, the **STOP.ps1** script deletes the task from Task Scheduler.

My question is: How can I exit the form with the STOP.ps1 script? at the moment it only has one line `Unregister-ScheduledTask -TaskName "TaskName" -Confirm:$false` which is to delete the task from Task Scheduler.

Comment: The first question here would probably be, why can't you do all of that in one script?

Comment: I could, but then it wouldn't work the way that I need it to.

Comment: I hear ya.. I can see the ENABLE being its own script.. but it makes no sense that the FORM script wouldn't do the STOP action on its own.  I mean no offense but this looks like a bad design.

Comment: I could add a button to the form that unregisters the task and closes the form... I just wanted to know if there was a way of doing it how I mentioned. I know of the other possibilities, and yes it may be a bad design, but my question wasn't on the topic of script design. I just want to know if what I asked is possible.

Comment: i would start the form with a named job, so that I could easily stop-job -name jobname. Could also find the process name of the script you are already running. Get-process -name *something* will do a contains search. You can pipe that to stop-process in your script.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could add a line to FORM.ps1 to export its $PID to a temporary file then use then import the $PID into your STOP.ps1 so you can kill the task.

for FORM.ps1 add

```
$PID | Out-File -FilePath $env:USERPROFILE\AppData\Local\Form.tmp
```

for STOP.ps1 use

```
$ErrorActionPreference = 'SilentlyContinue'
Unregister-ScheduledTask -TaskName "TaskName" -Confirm:$false
$FormPID = Get-Content $env:USERPROFILE\AppData\Local\Form.tmp
taskkill /pid $FormPID
```